# Magento importing and creating configurable products based on CSV (with children)

Tags: configurable-product, import, simple-product, avs-fastsimpleimport, automation

Magento importing and creating configurable products based on CSV (with children)

We are looking for a way of "scheduled" importing of products in Magento on server level (so no Magmi or other external tools).

I think we have 1 main question and this is: what is the de facto best method of doing this?

Secondly we have have T-shirts in sizes and this makes it a little bit more complex. Would the import file then contain all simple products? all simple products AND configurable products? or all configurable products (where the child relation attribute is concatenated)?

Currently we use a great tool for stock updates. We can learn it how a file works. How to translate certain fields. and it checks a certain folder every X hours.

I think we would be looking for a similar method where one can create "import profiles" that we can

- learn how to match headers with attributes
- learn how to translate foreign values to our values
- that creates configurable and simple products automatically
- and imports images from a remote url
- it then uploads all into a 'staging' table so we can check and enrich the values
- Then we can set it to live

It is probably far too much to ask - otherwise I would probably have found a solution already.

Does such an extension? or script exist?

I don't think default Magento import is the way to go.

Thanks! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Magento Native Product Import is 1 way to Import Products (Using DataFlow Profiles).

**Additionally, (DataFlow Profiles) can be setup as a cron like below:**

> 1. Create a custom module - Hoping you already know it.
> 2. Edit your config.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
     <Namespace_ModuleName>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
     </Namespace_ModuleName>
   </modules>
   <global>        
       <models>
         <testmodule>
           <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
           <resourceModel>testmodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </testmodule>
       </models>
    </global>    
    <crontab>
      <jobs>            
        <testmodule_mycustommethod>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>testmodule/cron::MyCustomMethod</model></run>
        </testmodule_mycustommethod>
      </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

> 3. Write the below method to execute your DataFlow Profiles
>      Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Cron

```
$profileId = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/config');

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}

Mage::log('Export ' . $profileId . ' Started.');

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');

Mage::log('Export ' . $profileId . ' Complete. BatchID: ' . $batchModel->getId());

echo "Export Complete. BatchID: " . $batchModel->getId() . "\n";
```

If you do not want to use Magmi, then there is an extension which is worth paying for it: uRapidFlow

> http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/product_import
>   https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/urapidflow.html

This does not AUTOMATE, however, you can write a CRON job as above for this as well since it will be similar to setting up a DataFlow Profile.

There is NO script that covers all the points mentioned above by you.

Let me know if this helps.